# Thymeleaf returning Java Exception message instead of my custom error message. How can I make it return what I want?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am implementing form validation and running into problems with BigInteger validation in thymeleaf's error messages. Here is my property annotation:

```
@Digits(integer = 9, fraction = 0, message="Must be a positive integer")
private BigInteger myInteger;
```

The Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public String whatever(@Valid @ModelAttribute Entity myEntity, BindingResult result) {
    
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "index";
        }
        //TODO
        return "index"; 
}
```

And finally, the HTML code

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('myEntity.myInteger')}"
th:errors="*{myEntity.myInteger}"></span>
```

Now, this is working fine for my other BigDecimal variables, but BigInteger causes Thymeleaf to display a `NumberFormatException` instead of my custom message `"Must be a positive integer."`, presumably because of some priority in error-handling that I am unfamiliar with. I have tried looking for answers but most of them direct me to some `messages.properties` based solution, which is not present in my project folder. What do I need to do to ensure my custom message is displayed instead of the `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: show your request i.e Entity

Comment: You can just create `messages.properties` in `resources` folder and add `typeMismatch.table.myInteger = Must be a positive integer `. Where `table` is your table name in lower case.

Comment: @Seldo97 Thank you so much! I had tried this before but it didn't work because I didn't type it in lower case, thank you for specifically pointing it out

Comment: @TypoTC I added the answer, you can mark it as solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create `messages.properties` in `resources` folder and add `typeMismatch.table.myInteger = Must be a positive integer` . Where "table" is your entity name in **lower case**.